# Gatsby: disappearing url parameters from email link

Tags: reactjs, parameters, gatsby

I'm developing a site in Gatsby. Users receive an email with a link containing a single-use token, like this:

https://www.example.com/approval?token=hIPdI7oSw6KV6k8ttsXG3XAHmIqExyB01YkChxiLR9leksJ67iRme6yyxfBztz3Z

This should take them to the `approval` page and supply the `token` as parameter.

It works fine in the development build, but in the production build the parameter is missing from the url and the user is simply directed to https://www.example.com/approval

Does anyone know why Gatsby might be re-writing the url without the parameter in the production build, and is there some way to prevent that from happening?

EDIT: This site is hosted on CloudFront, and we've enabled forwarding of query params. Possibly there are some a re-direct happening at another level?

Comment: is the parameter present in the URL as it is received in the e-mail ?

Answer (score 8):

It turned out to be Gatsby/CloudFront madness: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20139

The Gatsby dev server was unhelpfully injecting a `/` in front of the ?. The production build on CloudFront wasn't doing that, triggering a re-direct. CloudFront requires query strings in the format `/?` - for future reference!

Comment: I have already have the query param like `/?code=xxx` and have also added a redirect rule like `/tracking-url/?code=<*>` -> 200 Rewrite to `/tracking-url/?code=<*>`. My app is hosted on AWS Amplify. I can access the URL with the query param directly from the browser but the query param gets removed when I click the same link from the email.